# How can I select two columns from two tables?

Tags: sql

These are my tables

```
create table employees
(emp_no integer not null,
   emp_name char(25),
   age integer,
   department_id integer not null,
   salary integer,

   CONSTRAINT employees_pk PRIMARY KEY(emp_no),
   CONSTRAINT fk_Department FOREIGN KEY(department_id) 
                            REFERENCES Department(department_id));

insert into employees values ( 15,'sara',30 ,101 ,2000 )
insert into employees values ( 12,'maha',29 ,104 ,3000 )
insert into employees values ( 14,'ahmad',24 , 102,4400 )
insert into employees values ( 11,'ali', 27, 103, 2500)
insert into employees values ( 13,'nora', 35, 101,3500 )


create table Works
(emp_no integer not null,
   hurs integer,
   department_id integer not null,

   CONSTRAINT  Works_pk PRIMARY KEY(emp_no),
   CONSTRAINT Department_fk FOREIGN KEY(department_id)
                            REFERENCES Department(department_id));

insert into Works values ( 11,7,103)
insert into Works values (12,9,104)
insert into Works values (13,5,101)
insert into Works values (14,10,102)
insert into Works values (15,8,101)

create table Department
(Department_id integer not null,
   dep_name char(50),

   CONSTRAINT Department_pk PRIMARY KEY(Department_id));
 
insert into Department values (101,'computer')
insert into Department values (102,'history')
insert into Department values (103,'english')
insert into Department values (104,'physics')
```

And I want to select the employee names and their department names and these are my commands non worked properly:

```
select emp_name 
from employees 

select dep_name 
from Department

select emp_name 
from employees 
union 
select dep_name 
from Department

select emp_name, dep_name 
from Department 
cross join employees

SELECT employees.emp_name, Department.dep_name 
FROM employees, Department 
where employees.emp_name = Department.dep_name

select emp_name, Department.dep_name  
from employees 
inner JOIN Department on employees.emp_name = Department.dep_name

select 
    count(distinct employees.emp_name) 
from 
    employees 
where 
    employees.emp_name not in (select distinct Department.dep_name 
                               from Department)

select (employees.emp_name) 
from employees 
where employees.emp_name not in (select Department.dep_name 
                                 from Department)
```

Also I want to select employee name and sum of their salary who  are working hour is greater than or equal 20 and my command didn't work:

```
select 
    emp_name, sum(salary)
from 
    employees 
union 
select 
    hurs 
from 
    works 
where 
    hurs >= 20
```

Where did I go wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to get the workers' name and their department, you should be linking table `employees` and `department` using `department_id`, not name..

```
select emp_name,Department.dep_name
from employees inner JOIN Department
on employees.department_id = Department.Department_id
```

and for the employees whose working hours are >=20:

```
select employees.emp_name
from employees join works
on employees.emp_no=works.emp_no AND works.hurs>=20
```

and their total salary:

```
select sum(employees.salary)
from employees join works
on employees.emp_no=works.emp_no AND works.hurs>=20
```

note: `inner join` and `join` are the same thing..

In short, you should realize that linking the tables using `join` is relatively intuitive..
you are linking them based on the "same" column that the both tables own..
[one of them is a foreign key of the other (primary) key]

## UPDATE:

you can display the employees' names and their total salary together as the following, but it would seem redundant..

```
select employees.emp_name, sum(employees.salary)
from employees join works
on employees.emp_no=works.emp_no AND works.hurs>=20
group by employees.emp_name
```

Comment: this is great but i want it to show both of the two columns (emp_name and the sum of the salary )

Answer (score 0):

To union two `SELECT` results they have to have

- same selected column count
- same type of

What you actually want to use is `INNER JOIN` :

```
SELECT emp_name,sum(salary) FROM employees 
INNER JOIN works ON employees.emp_no = works.emp_no 
WHERE works.hurs >= 20
```

Comment: i got this msgMsg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "emp_no.employees" could not be bound.

Comment: it was in the wrong order at my first submit, fixed it.

Comment: now i got this Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'employees.emp_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is as follows:

```
SELECT employees.emp_name,
       Department.dep_name
FROM employees, Department
WHERE employees.department_id = Department.department_id
```

or with shorthand:

```
SELECT e.emp_name,
       d.dep_name
FROM employees as e, Department as d
WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id
```

A description of what is going on:

The `SELECT` section should contain a list of columns that you want separated by commas. You can explicitly reference a column from table as shown in the examples.

The `FROM` section should contain a list of tables you wish to join separated by commas. You can provide shorthand names for the tables, as shown in the second example.

The `WHERE` section allows you to mark which columns are related between the two tables.